# Unable to map base64 encoded string to Restful Implementation in JAXRS

Tags: java, web-services, rest, base64, jax-rs

I have to send an img from client side(javascript) to server side Jaxrs implementation.

Client side:

```
function sendRequest()
{
   var url = '<restservicepath>/uploadImage';
  $("body").append('<canvas id="theCanvas" style="display:none" width="300px"          height="300px"></canvas>');
  var canvas = document.getElementById('theCanvas');  
  var context = canvas.getContext('2d');
  var imageObj = new Image();
  imageObj.src = "myjpg.jpeg";  
  context.drawImage(imageObj, 0, 0, 300, 300);
  $.post(url, {'image':canvas.toDataURL("image/jpeg"), 'url':'caption'},     function(file){               
//Callback code
alert("done");
 });
}
```

And on server side in JAXRS I am using:

```
@POST
@Path("/uploadImage")
@Consumes("text/plain")
public Response upload(String image);
```

I am able to send the request to the webservice but not able to map i.e.,
I am not able to map the base64 encoded string to the server side string. How can I do that ?

Thanks!!

Answer (score 0):

Does this work?

```
@POST
@Path("/uploadImage")
@Consumes(MediaType.WILDCARD)
public Response upload(String image) {
    System.out.println(image);
    return Response.noContent().build();
}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot its working like a dream.Is there any reference for these MediaTypes?